# Are Androids immune to all inhalation effects? (Starfinder)

Tags: poison, starfinder, breathing

My party and I can't seem to come to a good agreement on the extent of the Constructed Racial trait with regards to breathing.

The Android [Constructed](https://www.starjammersrd.com/races/androids/) racial trait reads:

> ...androids do not breathe or suffer the normal environmental effects of being in a vacuum.

*[Starfinder #36: Professional Courtesy pg. 47](https://aonsrd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=722)* expanded on this, saying that androids could not drown:

> Certain effects, such as androids’ constructed racial trait, the life bubble spell, and the water breathing universal creature rule allow creatures to mitigate or ignore [suffocation from drowning].

My initial interpretation of this was:

1. Androids do not breathe, and therefore do not interact with the *Breathing* game mechanic, which is

   - used as an infection mechanism in certain diseases and poisons, and
   - used in the suffocation mechanics found in water, vacuums, and other situations where air would be limited.
2. Further, they do not suffer the bludgeoning damage, etc, caused by sudden or prolonged exposure to a vacuum.

My party is of the opinion that this would be rather overpowered, and that the breathing mention should rather be read as supporting text to the succeeding phrase. This could then be rephrased as:

- "Androids do not suffer any ill effects caused by vacuums, since they don't really need to breathe."

This argument is supported by the fact that the text takes time to specifically mention that androids have *resistance* to poisons, but fails to mention the far-reaching effects and flat-out immunity that would be provided by the total non-participation in this gaming mechanic.

Am I over thinking this? What would the correct interpretation of this be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CRB pg. 417 states

> An inhaled affliction is delivered the moment a creature
> that breathes (and isn’t wearing a space suit or suit of armor
> that filters out such toxins) enters an area containing such an
> affliction.

An android is not "a creature that breathes".  Therefore an android is not affected by *inhaled* afflictions.

This might seem overpowered, but consider that characters in Starfinder will *often* be wearing full environmental protection of one sort or another.

Comment: Thanks! This is very clear. I had looked through the rulebook but missed this part.